# Why does a Bacon.combineAsArray Stream of 'keyup' events immediately end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frp, bacon.js

I need to create a `Bacon.Property` that gets either `true` or `false` if multiple html input contain their correct char. (They all have to be correct, if not, the property needs to be `false`)

To achieve this, I created an `Array` of eventStreams via jquery.bacons `asEventStream` helper and used bacons `combineAsArray` to create a "allInputsAreCorrect" stream.

And this is when I fail. 
The "allInputsAreCorrect" immediatly ends. And **after** ending, it once calls my `onValue` callback (?). Did I get something completely wrong, or is their a better way to combine all those inputs into one `Property`?

Here are the corresponding parts from my code, I tried to comment everything as best as possible:

```
var phraseCorrect,
    phraseStream = Bacon.combineAsArray((function () {
        // Using jQuery.map to convert inputs
        // into an Array of eventStreams:
        return $('.keyphrase-list input')
            .map(mapFromInputToStream);
    }()));

// This is how I would like to create the Property..
// But the Stream doesnt fire, so this is unimportant for now.
phraseCorrect = phraseStream.toProperty(false);

phraseStream
    .onEnd(function () {
        // This gets called immediately..
        // And I dont get why.
        console.log('End?? Why????');
    });

phraseStream
    .onValue(function (values) {
        // This gets called **once**
        // (right after the onEnd logging.. ???)
        console.log('Gets called once', values);
    });
```

The mapping function that creates the `keyup` `eventStreams`:

```
function mapFromInputToStream() {
    var $input = $(this);

    // I commented out some mapping and filtering.
    // But even without `map` and `filter` it doesnt work.
    return $input
        .asEventStream('keyup');
        // .map(someMapping)
        // .filter(someFiltering);
}
```

This code logs the following:

```
End?? Why????
Gets called once [b.fn.b.init[17]]
```

(there are 17 inputs)

After that, typing anything in one of the html inputs doesnt trigger any callbacks.

I would appreciate if someone could give me *an explanation for this behaviour* (the immediatly ending stream).
But of course, any hints on how to fix this (with bacon.js) are welcome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) so that you pass a real array to Bacon, not a jQuery object (that is returned by [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)). Bacon will mistake that for a constant (since it's not `instanceof Array`), and return an ended, constant property.

```
var phraseCorrect = Bacon.combineAsArray($('.keyphrase-list input')
                                         .map(mapFromInputToStream)
                                         .get());
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know that jQuery.map doesnt return true arrays... Anyhow, the combined stream *now* doesnt trigger anything, also with `.get` or `.toArray`.. any thoughts on this?

Comment: [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) does, [`jQuery.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) doesn't. Notice that `phraseCorrect` (from my code) is not a stream, `combineAsArray` always returns properties right away. Make sure to have your listeners not attached to `phraseStream`

Comment: I guess the rest is my problem.. ;) But you answered my question, so I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: **Well** everything was correct! I just was too stupid to type in all inputs.. Thanks again :)